# Running XSP4 in MonoDevelop 2.6

Tags: asp.net, monodevelop, xsp

After a fresh install of Ubuntu 11.10, which comes with Mono 2.10, I've found myself in a bit of a pickle: I can't run ASP.Net 4.0 projects, even though I have XSP4 installed. It's almost as if it expects there to only be an xsp2...

Here's the error:

```
Could not launch web server. The "xsp2" web server cannot be started. Please ensure that it is installed.
```

Details:

```
MonoDevelop.Core.UserException: The "xsp2" web server cannot be started. Please ensure that it is installed.
  at MonoDevelop.AspNet.AspNetExecutionHandler.GetXspPath (MonoDevelop.AspNet.AspNetExecutionCommand cmd) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 
  at MonoDevelop.AspNet.AspNetExecutionHandler.Execute (MonoDevelop.Core.Execution.ExecutionCommand command, IConsole console) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 
  at MonoDevelop.Core.Execution.DefaultExecutionHandler.Execute (MonoDevelop.Core.Execution.ExecutionCommand command, IConsole console) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 
  at MonoDevelop.AspNet.AspNetAppProject.DoExecute (IProgressMonitor monitor, MonoDevelop.Projects.ExecutionContext context, MonoDevelop.Projects.ConfigurationSelector config) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0
```

Any idea what the problem for this could be? Is XSP4 only compatible with MonoDevelop 2.8?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Assuming you are using monodevelop, Go to Project menu select your "application option" not solution option.In the dialog box that appears, under "Build" select "General", then on the right pane change "Runtime Version" to Mono/.Net 4.0

VB.NET addin seems no to support .NET 4.0 ([see this stackoverflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9623964/new-default-vb-net-project-immediately-gives-an-error)) but I found that just creating a symbolic link (xsp2->xsp4) was enough to run Mono/.Net 3.5 on mono-xsp4