# Java Console Error in MonoDevelop

Tags: java, monodevelop, ubuntu-11.10

So, I'm tinkering around with MonoDevelop on my ubuntu 11.10 64-bit, and when I tried to run a Java console application I got this error immediately when opening the new project:

**Error while trying to load the project '/home/myhomefolder/documents/java/project.jproj': Project does not support framework'.NETFramework,Version=v4.0'**

What can I do to resolve this error?

Comment: Extra Info: I tried looking for an update that would supply a fix, and couldn't find anything. In fact, that is how I was directed to the stackoverflow website. There is a link from monoproject to this site for questions. So I thought I'd give it a try. Should I just switch to netbeans for java, or is this fixable? I don't know all of the ins and outs of the mono IDE yet, so this may be something simple.

Comment: Are you trying to open a Java Project to work with it in the Mono IDE? Mono is essentially .net, so it is not made to work with Java from my understanding.

Comment: .NET is a microsoft framework

Comment: Yes jschoen, I am trying to open a new Java Project in mono, and mono allows for Java applications when starting a new project. So I think it is feasible to think that maybe it's available somehow for the mono IDE.

Comment: Yes, .NET is a microsoft framework. Thank you for that. The Answer to the Ultimate Question of Life, The Universe, and Everything is 42.

Answer (score 1):

You can try changing the project format default from Visual Studio 2010 to Visual Studio 2008. (Edit/Preferences/"Load/Save"). That worked for me on Ubuntu 12.04.

As a side note, this fix also works for Visual Basic projects ([New default VB.NET project immediately gives an error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9623964/new-default-vb-net-project-immediately-gives-an-error))